# Ubuntu 18.04.5: Slow boot without ethernet

Tags: boot, networking, ethernet

When my computer is connected to ethernet, everything works fine. Without the cable, there are two problems: the booting is slow (it takes several minutes) and the computer does not automatically connect to wi-fi. The computer "thinks" it is connected to ethernet, as can be seen in the picture. I solve it by removing the "imaginary" ethernet connection but it is tiring to do each time I turn on the computer.

[image]

I tried to solve it myself and I had a theory that it has something to do with MAC addresses because of the last line of my `NetworkManager.conf` file (see below). I tried switching it to `yes` but it did not work.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Additional files
`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

`/etc/netplan/*.yaml` (only one file `01-network-manager-all.yaml`)

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Opening enp3s0:
[image]

Opening ifupdown:
[image]

Could you please give me a hint where the problem might be?

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Set back wifi.scan-rand-mac-address. Is your wifi connection profile set to auto-connect?

Comment: It is a desktop installation. And yes, the wi-fi connection profile is set to auto-connect.

Comment: Thanks for the data. Is this Ubuntu, or something else? Show me what you see when you click on the settings icon for ifupdown and enp3s0. Do you ever need to run without the ethernet cable plugged in? Why?

Comment: Status please...

Comment: The justus95's answer worked. I need to run without the ethernet cable in campus. Actually, I ignored the problem for a few months before I finally decided to solve it. Thank you both.

Comment: Thanks for the update... however, I don't think justus95's answer is the best solution... I think the problem is elsewhere. I suspect the ifupdown process. You never answered my question about whether this is standard Ubuntu, or something else... or the screenshots that I requested.

Comment: Yes, it is standard Ubuntu. Sorry, I'll send the screenshots. Sorry for the Czech, hopefully it is understandable.

Comment: Try my answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your help but what should be the advantage of your answer in comparison to the justus95's answer?

Comment: It doesn't require editing /etc/network/interfaces, or the use of a CLI command to bring up enp3s0, or manually use ifupdown. All interaction is through the GUI. Try it.

Comment: @heynnema Ok, I'll try it (maybe tomorrow, I got busy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to this...

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Set `/etc/network/interfaces` to this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Set your enp3s0 connection profile to **Connect Automatically**.

Reboot with ethernet cable disconnected.

**Note**: Your `ifupdown (enp3s0)` interface settings should not be showing anymore.

If there's still a 2 minute delay at boot time, just disable **Connect Automatically** in your enp3s0 connection profile, when you know you're going to use the computer on campus without an ethernet cable connected.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing you /etc/network/interfaces file and changing this line "auto enp3s0" to "manual enp3s0". This should tell the system that, when you want to use this interface that you will manually up/down it, and during boot it shouldn't wait for and confirm that the interface is up.

Comment: Thank you, now it works on wi-fi. I am going to use ethernet on weekend and hopefully, it will connect automatically, too. But even if it does not, it is still an improvement.